# Google Heatmap Not Consistently Displaying in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

I have a htm FILE that displays 1 pin and 1 heat map around that pin using the Google Maps API (simplified for test case).

This file consistently opens correctly (see both pin and heat map) on Safari 9.0.2, Chrome 47.0.2526.106, and Firefox 42.0 - all on Mac OS X 10.9.5 running on a Macbook Air (Early 2014) with 8GB memory/1.7 GHz i7.

However, it does not open consistently under Internet Explorer 11. Specifically, the map pin will show and the info window will open when the pin is clicked, but the heat map won't show.

On IE 11.0.9600.18125 running on Windows 8.1 (Parallels VM on Mac), I noticed that IE was opening the code below under document mode 7 instead of "Edge". I checked the "Compatibility View Settings" under Tools and noticed that the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" was checked.  When I uncheck this box and reload the htm file, the heat map displays correctly.

Question 1: Is there anything in the code below that would cause IE 11 to think this is a docmode 7 file?

On two Dell Latitude PC's running IE 11: the heat map displays correctly on one PC but does NOT display the heat map on the other PC - with AND without the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" checkbox on/off. Docmode was correctly read as "Edge" in all cases on both PCs. So now I'm wondering if the above relates to running IE in a VM in Parallels.

I've searched SO and came across similar problems that seem to relate to the timing of AJAX data calls that don't finish before the heat map is displayed: [google maps v3 heatmap not displaying on page load.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996350/google-maps-v3-heatmap-not-displaying-on-page-load)

Here is the code from the htm file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <style type="text/css">
                html {
                    height: 100%;
                    font-size: small
                }

            body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px
            }

            #map_canvas {
                min-height: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }

            #cBoxes {
                position: absolute;
                right: 5px;
                top: 50px;
                background: white
            }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization">
                </script>
            <script language="javascript">
                var marker
                var map
                var markersdataSpDf7735 = [];
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.475989, -71.409459),
                    map: map,
                    title: "Name: A\rBurgersSold: 100",
                    clickable: true,
                    draggable: false,
                    flat: true,
                    visible: true,
                    zIndex: null
                    });
            markersdataSpDf7735.push(marker);

            var markersdataSpDf5372Data = [{
                location: new google.maps.LatLng(42.475989, -71.409459),
                weight: 100
                }];

            var markersdataSpDf5372 = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: markersdataSpDf5372Data,
                dissipating: false,
                radius: 0.5
                });

            function showO(MLPArray, boxname, map) {
                for (var i = 0; i < MLPArray.length; i++) {
                    MLPArray[i].setMap(map);
                }
                document.getElementById(boxname).checked = true;
            }

            function hideO(MLPArray, boxname) {
                for (var i = 0; i < MLPArray.length; i++) {
                    MLPArray[i].setMap(null);
                }
                document.getElementById(boxname).checked = false;
            }

            function boxclick(box, MLPArray, boxname, map) {
                if (box.checked) {
                    showO(MLPArray, boxname, map);
                } else {
                    hideO(MLPArray, boxname);
                }
            }

            function showHeatmap(MLPArray, boxname, map) {
                MLPArray.setMap(map);
                document.getElementById(boxname).checked = true;
            }

            function hideHeatmap(MLPArray, boxname) {
                MLPArray.setMap(null);
                document.getElementById(boxname).checked = false;
            }

            function boxclickHeatmap(box, MLPArray, boxname, map) {
                if (box.checked) {
                    showHeatmap(MLPArray, boxname, map);
                } else {
                    hideHeatmap(MLPArray, boxname);
                }
            }

            function initialize() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.475989, -71.409459);

                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                    disableDefaultUI: false,
                    disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
                    draggable: true,
                    keyboardShortcuts: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT
                    },
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
                    },
                    noClear: false,
                    scaleControl: true,
                    scaleControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ScaleControlStyle.STANDARD
                    },
                    scrollwheel: true,
                    streetViewControl: false
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

                map.fitBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                    new google.maps.LatLng(42.475989, -71.409459),
                    new google.maps.LatLng(42.475989, -71.409459)));

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: '',
                    disableAutoPan: false,
                    maxWidth: 330,
                    pixelOffset: null
                    });

                google.maps.event.addListener(markersdataSpDf7735[0], 'click', function(event) {
                    infowindow.setContent('Name: A <br>BurgersSold: 100');
                    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                    infowindow.open(map, markersdataSpDf7735[0])
                });

                showO(markersdataSpDf7735, "markersdataSpDf7735box", map);
                showHeatmap(markersdataSpDf5372, "markersdataSpDf5372box", map);

            }
            </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>


        <div id="cBoxes">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="markersdataSpDf7735box" onClick='boxclick(this,markersdataSpDf7735,"markersdataSpDf7735box",map);' /> <b>Drop Pins</b> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="markersdataSpDf5372box" onClick='boxclickHeatmap(this,markersdataSpDf5372,"markersdataSpDf5372box",map);' /> <b>Heatmap</b> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here is what you should see:

[image: Correct Display]

Question 2: Are there any obvious things that are wrong with the html/javascript code?

The maddening thing about this is that is works in IE on one laptop but not another. Both are corporate laptops that are configured the same. On both laptops, the htm file opens correctly in Chrome.  Any IE settings that might need to be set?

Thanks for any pointers on where to look.

Comment: To answer question 1: IE has settings that force compatibility mode on intranet sites. Try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` in your head tag to see if that corrects the issue.

Comment: @TahTatsumoto Thanks for this tip. This fixes the problem on my Mac - running IE 11 on Windows 8.1 in a Parallels virtual machine.  I've sent the file to my client to test on his Dell laptop and will report back if it works for him.

Comment: Just to report back - this fix does not resolve the issue on my client's Dell laptop running IE 11. We've opened a standard Google heat map (which also failed), and checked docmode to ensure that it was "Edge". Any other ideas on what to check?